# Back up of data from one index in elastic search and restore it with modified mappings/settings

Tags: elasticsearch

Let us say I currently have an index named `product`. I want to copy all the documents(data) from this index, along with the mappings/settings. I then want to delete this index `product` and restore the data from the backup with a modified mapping/setting. How can this be done. I have looked at `elasticdump`. Can I use this? Also do I need to re index the data, if so how do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Snapshot/Restore API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restore-snapshot-api.html) allows you to change index settings (except `number_of_shards`), but not mappings (doesn't make sense), when you restore an index.

For instance, the command below restores the product index, but sets the replica count to 0

```
POST /_snapshot/my_repo/product_snapshot/_restore
{
  "indices": "product",
  "include_aliases": false,
  "index_settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  }
}
```

There's also an option called `ignore_index_settings` where you can list index settings to ignore when restoring the index (again except `number_of_shards`).

If you want to be able to modify the mappings as well, then you need to use the [Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) that allows you to physically copy your product index into another index with different settings and mappings.

Comment: thanks a lot i think i will go with the second method using reindex api